# Electron separate from an atom -- still has same characteristics about location?

Tags: electrons, atomic-physics, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle

I have heard that a single electron has been trapped for a long time in I guess some kind of magnetic trap. I also understand that an electron in orbit around a proton in hydrogen atom is not really in a smooth planetary orbit but it is more like it "probably" is some place around the proton. So my question is, does a trapped electron exhibit this same probability of location in the trap or do we know by virtue of it being trapped a lot more about its location?

Comment: An electron that is "captured" by a nucleus is very similar to an electron that is captured in a trap. This is why some of the earlier literature on single-particle traps refers to the trap/particle system a "geonium atom".

Answer (score 0):

A 'magnetic trap' can be considered to be some sort of electromagnetic potential.The Schrodinger equation for a electron covers this as well so inside the magnetic trap the electron would be much more probable to be found after a measurement on the electron.

Answer (score 0):

In [this early experiment](https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.31.1279) for trapping electrons in a [Penning trap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Penning_trap),they talk of orbits,

> Another noteworthy point
> is the small size of the orbit which minimizes
> field homogeneity problems; e.g. , in the experiments on an 80 K electron to be described, the
> cyclotron orbit diameter is -1 p. m while the
> axial extension of the orbit is -200 pm. In view
> of the foregoing it becomes profitable to look
> upon the monoelectron oscillator as a fixed-in-
> space pseudoatom free of first- and second-or-
> der Doppler shifts, whose various energy leve1. s
> are accessible both experimentally and theoreti-
> cally to great accuracy.

My impression is that the corresponding orbital in the trap , ( [orbitals](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Chemical/eleorb.html) describe the probabilistic location of an electron in an atom according to the probabilistic theory of quantum mechanics ) is compressed in space in the Penning trap.  Similar to the way that the corresponding orbital of the nucleus in an atom , because of its very small distribution in space, allow the nucleus to be modeled as  a point.